# Filtering by bounty ignored for new messages pushed from the server

Tags: bug, search, filtering

I just noticed small bug while browsing bounty questions. Server is ignoring my "Has bounty" filter and notifies me about new questions without bounty.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Clicking this "3 questions with new activity" loads questions without bounty (those 2 at the top have been loaded this way):

[image]

I think either server should not push info about new questions which don't satisfy current filter, or client should adjust this info according to current filter.

---

**Added:** refreshing the page leaves only bounty questions, as expected.

Comment: I wonder if the [php] tag has something to do with it ;-)

Comment: Your screenshot went belly up. Mind uploading it on imgur?